# ASP.NET Chart Preview tooltip Undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, tooltip

I am currently working on a project and I am attempting to create a chart preview, I keep receiving the error tooltip undefined but when I debug the code it shows as defined. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my code for the class with the tooltip,

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        lblException.Visible = false;

        if (!IsPostBack) {
            string con_string = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CHDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_string);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUBSTRING(NursingUnitID, 1, 1) AS Floor, COUNT(*) AS Patients " +
                                            "FROM Admissions " +
                                            "WHERE SUBSTRING(NursingUnitID, 1, 1) IN ('1', '2', '3') " +
                                            "AND DischargeDate IS NULL " +
                                            "GROUP BY SUBSTRING(NursingUnitID, 1, 1)", con);

            try {
                using (con) {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    chtFloor.Series["Series1"].Name = "Patients";
                    chtFloor.Series["Patients"].Points.DataBindXY(reader, "Floor",reader, "Patients");

                    chtFloor.Width = 600;
                    chtFloor.Height = 600;
                    chtFloor.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;

                    chtFloor.Titles.Add(new Title("Number of Current Patients on Each Floor", Docking.Top, new Font("Arial", 20f), Color.Black));
                    chtFloor.Titles.Add(new Title("Nursing Unit", Docking.Bottom, new Font("Arial", 12f, FontStyle.Bold), Color.Black));

                    chtFloor.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("AliceBlue");

                    foreach (Series series in chtFloor.Series)
                    {
                        for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < series.Points.Count; pointIndex++)
                        {
                            string toolTip = "<img src=nursing_units_preview.aspx?Floor=" + series.Points[pointIndex].AxisLabel + " />";
                            series.Points[pointIndex].MapAreaAttributes = "onmouseover=\"DisplayTooltip('" + toolTip + "');\" onmouseout=\"DisplayTooltip('');\"";
                            series.Points[pointIndex].Url = "nursing_units.aspx?Floor=" + series.Points[pointIndex].AxisLabel;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblException.Text = ex.ToString();
                lblException.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my code for the chart preview,

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public partial class nursing_units_preview : System.Web.UI.Page {

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            String floor = Request.QueryString.ToString();

            if (floor.IndexOf("=") != -1)
            {
                floor = floor.Substring(floor.IndexOf("=") + 1);

                // Convert %2f to /
                if (floor.IndexOf("%2f") != -1)
                    floor = floor.Replace("%2f", "/");

                // Convert + to " "
                if (floor.IndexOf("+") != -1)
                    floor = floor.Replace("+", " ");
            }

            String titleFloor = "";
            switch (floor)
            {
                case "1": titleFloor = "1st";
                    break;
                case "2": titleFloor = "2nd";
                    break;
                case "3": titleFloor = "3rd";
                    break;
                default: titleFloor = "Error";
                    break;
            }

            string con_string = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CHDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_string);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NursingUnitID AS Unit, COUNT(*) AS Patients FROM Admissions WHERE SUBSTRING(NursingUnitID, 1, 1) = @floor AND DischargeDate IS NULL GROUP BY NursingUnitID", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("floor", floor);

            try
            {
                using (con)
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    chtNursingUnits.Series["Series1"].Name = "Patients";

                    foreach (Series ser in chtNursingUnits.Series)
                    {
                        ser.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
                    }

                    chtNursingUnits.Series["Patients"].Points.DataBindXY(reader, "Unit", reader, "Patients");

                    chtNursingUnits.Width = 600;
                    chtNursingUnits.Height = 600;
                    chtNursingUnits.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;

                    chtNursingUnits.Titles.Add(new Title("Number of Current Patients on " + titleFloor + " Floor", Docking.Top, new Font("Arial", 20f), Color.Black));
                    chtNursingUnits.Titles.Add(new Title("Nursing Unit", Docking.Bottom, new Font("Arial", 12f, FontStyle.Bold), Color.Black));

                    chtNursingUnits.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("AliceBlue");
                    chtNursingUnits.RenderType = RenderType.BinaryStreaming;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I forgot to create the javascript functions that the code uses below I added this javascript and it fixed the problem.

```html
<script>
        function DisplayTooltip(tooltip_text) {
            fadingTooltip.innerHTML = tooltip_text;
            tooltip_shown = (tooltip_text != "") ? true : false;
            if (tooltip_text != "") {
                // Get tooltip window height
                tooltip_height = (fadingTooltip.style.pixelHeight) ? fadingTooltip.style.pixelHeight : fadingTooltip.offsetHeight;
                transparency = 0;
                ToolTipFading();
            }
            else {
                clearTimeout(timer_id);
                fadingTooltip.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }

        function DisplayTooltip(tooltip_text) {
            fadingTooltip.innerHTML = tooltip_text;
            tooltip_shown = (tooltip_text != "") ? true : false;
            if (tooltip_text != "") {
                // Get tooltip window height
                tooltip_height = (fadingTooltip.style.pixelHeight) ? fadingTooltip.style.pixelHeight : fadingTooltip.offsetHeight;
                transparency = 0;
                ToolTipFading();
            }
            else {
                clearTimeout(timer_id);
                fadingTooltip.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }

        function AdjustToolTipPosition(e) {
            if (tooltip_shown) {
                // Depending on IE/Firefox, find out what object to use to find mouse position
                var ev;
                if (e)
                    ev = e;
                else
                    ev = event;

                fadingTooltip.style.visibility = "visible";
                offset_y = (ev.clientY + tooltip_height - document.body.scrollTop + 30 >= wnd_height) ? -15 - tooltip_height : 20;
                fadingTooltip.style.left = Math.min(wnd_width - tooltip_width - 10, Math.max(3, ev.clientX + 6)) + document.body.scrollLeft + 'px';
                fadingTooltip.style.top = ev.clientY + offset_y + document.body.scrollTop + 'px';
            }
        }

        function WindowLoading() {
            fadingTooltip = document.getElementById('fadingTooltip');

            // Get tooltip  window width    
            tooltip_width = (fadingTooltip.style.pixelWidth) ? fadingTooltip.style.pixelWidth : fadingTooltip.offsetWidth;

            // Get tooltip window height
            tooltip_height = (fadingTooltip.style.pixelHeight) ? fadingTooltip.style.pixelHeight : fadingTooltip.offsetHeight;

            UpdateWindowSize();
        }

        function ToolTipFading() {
            if (transparency <= 100) {
                fadingTooltip.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + transparency + ")";
                fadingTooltip.style.opacity = transparency / 100;
                transparency += 5;
                timer_id = setTimeout('ToolTipFading()', 35);
            }
        }

        function UpdateWindowSize() {
            wnd_height = document.body.clientHeight;
            wnd_width = document.body.clientWidth;
        }
    </script>
```